# In Azure devops how can i refer to a specific azure library group variable in a powershell inline code

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I build various VMS in different regions. Currently i have created a variable group for each region.

However without unlinking and linking variable groups for each region all the time to a pipleline, if i link them all how can i refer to a specific variable in a variable group in powershell ?

eg variable group called region1 has a variable called vnetname which equals vnet-region1
variable group called region2 also has a variable called vnetname which has the value vnet-region2

so i if link both those variable groups to my pipeline and want to build a vm in region 1, how can I refer to the variable "vnetname" in the region1 variable group in the inline powershell script ?

Answer (score 0):

**It is not recommended to define a variable with the same name in different variable groups**.

When you use the same variable name in different variable group in the same pipeline  the variable group included last in your YAML file will set the variable's value.

That means that the variable value in the variable group written later will overwrite the variable value in the variable group written first.

Here is the reference [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64457522/15968720) for more information about usage of multiple variable groups have same Same variable but different variable values in the pipelines.