# specifying which variable group to use

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i want to create several variable groups which all have the same variable names but different values.

for example, groupa and groupb
each has variables var1 and var2

How can i name the specific variable group and variable, e.g. groupa.var2 in the pipeline?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? How do you plan to drive which variable group is referenced? What does your pipeline look like? Are you using classic pipelines or YAML pipelines?

Comment: the documentation doesn't show how to access different groups. at least i have not seen anything (if you can refer it to me that would be great!) i have seen precedence, but not what i am looking for. for testing my pipeline has just one step, which is PowerShell to Write the value of the variables. i am using classic - i cannot use YAML since i am using TFS

Answer (score 1):

> How can i name the specific variable group and variable, e.g. groupa.var2 in the pipeline?

Whether we use classic mode or YAML, it is not recommended to define a variable with the same name in different variable groups. Because when you refer to different variable groups containing the same variable name in the same pipeline, you cannot avoid stepping on each other.

That means that the variable value in the variable group written later will overwrite the variable value in the variable group written first.

You could check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449524/resolve-azure-yaml-pipeline-overlapping-variable-names-in-multiple-variable-grou/64457522#64457522) for some more details.

Answer (score 1):

apparently you cannot have the same variable names in different variable groups.

i have not tried it but perhaps you can

1. create a pipeline variable called VariableGroupToUse
2. Create Variable Groups VariableGroupA and VariableGroupB
3. Create a variable in **each** group, with a prefix, e.g. VariableGroupA.Value and VariableGroupB.Value
4. in the pipeline refer to the variable as $(VariableGroupToUse).Value
5. Set/Change the VariableGroupToUse value to either VariableGroupA o VariableGroupB